# Queue (SQS) with Mandrill Mail Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I want to create a mailer micro-service wrapping the mandrill api so that all of my serivces don't need to be aware of our mandrill API Keys. Ideally I would have a message queue and upon adding a message to the queue the lambda would send a call to mandrill to send the email.

However there are two issues with this approach.

1. SQS does not have a trigger for lambdas.
2. this is transactional in nature, and I want to avoid sending an email and having the lambda time out before I can delete the message from the queue so it isn't sent again.

The issue here is that per `readMessage` call I can get a max of 10 messages.  Why is this?  I figure they want people to use SES for this but what would be a good way to get this functionality?  The hope was that this would be asynchronous and not need to be attached to our API so we can avoid authenticating the request.

What is a good architecture solution for this service?

Comment: *"The issue here is that per readMessage call I can get a max of 10 messages. Why is this?"*  Why is that an issue?  The idea is that if you fetch a handful of messages, process them, and delete them from the queue.  If speed (messages/sec) is a priority, you would almost certainly address that by having multiple consumers -- each of which automatically gets a set of messages that are not currently in flight (i.e. currently being processed bt another consumer).  In an application like this, you would probably only want to fetch 1, not 10, at a time, handle it, then delete from the queue.

Comment: Note also that AWS has promised a future SQS+Lambda integration, but had not provided any dates.